# Mean Variance Optimisation Under Weights Constraints

Tags: r, optimization, portfolio

I would like to find the weights for the portfolio that maximises the sharpe ration for a 3 risky assets case. The sum of the weights of all assets should equal 2, the weight of asset1 is forced to 1  and  all assets weights >=0 (i.e the problem would be to maximise the portfolio  risk adjusted return  by adjusting only the weights for asset asset 2 and 3 subject to them not being more than 1 and >=0). Is this the right way of programing the problem using quadprog ?

```
    library(quadprog)
    covmat <- matrix(c(3.235343e-02, -3.378191e-03, -1.544574e-05,
                       -3.378191e-03,  8.769166e-03,  1.951734e-06,
                       -1.544574e-05,  1.951734e-06,  2.186799e-06),3,3)


    A <- rbind(c(1,1,1),diag(3))
    b <- c(2,1,0,0)  # those are the constraints, sum of weights are 2 and weights of asset1 = 1 
    c <- c(0,0.1,0.05)  # those are the assets returns, asset1 hasd a zero return but I want him to have a 100% weight out of the available 200% in my problem

# solve QP model
    solve.QP(covmat,dvec=c,Amat=t(A),bvec=b,meq=2)$solution
```

Answer (score 0):

Solve.QP is not optimizing Sharpe ratio (SR). As explained in the help `?solve.QP`, it is minimizing this function:

```
min(-d^T b + 1/2 b^T D b) with the constraints A^T b >= b_0.
```

If you want to maximize SR try this [http://comisef.wikidot.com/tutorial%3atangencyportfolio](http://comisef.wikidot.com/tutorial%3Atangencyportfolio)
But apparently that is for optimization without restrictions.

Well, it is possible to optimize minimizing the risk for several given returns. In other words, identify a relevant segment of the efficient frontier (EF) with restrictions, and compute the Sharpe ratio (SR). The tangent obviously will be that portfolio that maximizes the SR.

Given your data and restrictions:

```
#Find EF
#Min variance portfolio
aMat <- cbind(rep(1,nrow(covmat)),diag(1,nrow(covmat)))
bVec  <- c(2,1,0,0)
zeros <- array(0, dim = c(nrow(covmat),1))
solQP <- solve.QP(covmat, zeros, aMat, bVec, meq = 1)

# weights and return for minimum variance portfolio
w.mv <- solQP$solution
r.mv<-t(w.mv) %*% excret

#Identify tangent approximately
#for that find min var portfolio for a relevant sequence of returns
#adding a return restriction to the optimization

sret<-seq(r.mv,max(excret)*1.1,length.out =50) #the maximum by try and error
sret<-sort(unique(c(max(excret),sret)))

rp=array(r.mv,1)
sp=sqrt(t(w.mv) %*% covmat %*% w.mv)
wp=t(matrix(w.mv))
aMatt <- cbind(excret,aMat)
# solve min var for every given return
for (ri in sret[-1]){
  bVect  <- c(ri,bVec)
  solQP <- solve.QP(covmat, zeros, aMatt, bVect, meq = 2)
  wp=rbind(wp, solQP$solution)
  rp<-c(rp,t(solQP$solution) %*% excret)
  sp<-c(sp,sqrt(t(solQP$solution) %*% covmat %*% solQP$solution))
}
IS=rp/sp #sharpe index
cbind(wp,sp,rp,IS)
wp[which.max(IS),] #tangent
cbind(wp,sp,rp,IS)[which.max(IS),]
plot(c(sp,diag(covmat)^.5),c(rp,excret))

#As you can see in the plot you have a corner solution
(c.sol<-c(1,1,0))
c(st=sqrt(t(c.sol) %*% covmat %*% c.sol),
rt=t(c.sol) %*% excret,
ISt=t(c.sol) %*% excret/sqrt(t(c.sol) %*% covmat %*% c.sol))
```

The output will be:

```
> wp[which.max(IS),] #tangent
[1] 1.00000000 0.98339763 0.01660237
> cbind(wp,sp,rp,IS)[which.max(IS),]
                                         sp         rp 
1.00000000 0.98339763 0.01660237 0.18490315 0.09916988 
        IS 
0.53633418 
> plot(c(sp,diag(covmat)^.5),c(rp,excret))
> (c.sol<-c(1,1,0))
[1] 1 1 0
> c(st=sqrt(t(c.sol) %*% covmat %*% c.sol),
+ rt=t(c.sol) %*% excret,
+ ISt=t(c.sol) %*% excret/sqrt(t(c.sol) %*% covmat %*% c.sol))
       st        rt       ISt 
0.1853813 0.1000000 0.5394288
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Robert, but this does not really help me. I need to optimise the sharpe ratio for a 3 assets portfolio with sum of weights = 2. Asset 1 being of weight 1 (constraint) and the  other assets with w 2 & w3 >=0 & w2+w3=1 , (no short sales allowed). The example  is for an unconstrained  short sales (no constraint on weights). I would also like to specify my own co-variance matrix and expected returns so that I can use my own robust estimators...do you know of any other packages that could do this or is there  a way of using solve.QP for this (I assumed so from your link...)  ?

Comment: Thank you Robert, this is  a very elegant way to derive the solution and exactely what I was after. I assume that increasing the number of portfolios will increase the accuracy but also the computation time.